# What if I don't submit my application to google marketplace?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Through reading the the flow of registration and development for google marketplace apps, a funny idea came to my mind: after finishing the tests(continuously install and test) for my app(base on web application), can I avoid to submit(never click "Submit for approval") the app to google marketplace so that I could use it privately(may be longtime or forever)? Anyone tried this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install or publish your applications from/to the marketplace. You can [sideload](http://www.androidcentral.com/what-sideloading-android-z) your app and use it for as long as you want. You could even submit it to an [alternative marketplace](http://danatheteacher.hubpages.com/hub/Top-Android-Market-Alternative-App-Stores).

Comment: it based on web application instead of android or other devices.I want this app could be installed in google app account so that I could turn on/off the app for specify organization, therefore I think I must publish it to marketplace.... is that right?

Comment: If that is the case then you should update your question to include more details.

Comment: so... I could use my own developped app for my own domain users privately via avoiding submission? Anyone has such experiense?

Comment: You can give your APK file to anyone to install (see the first link in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just avoid submitting (this is the "old way" of having in-house apps on the More menu).

There is now though a new, better way if you want to add functionality for your own Google Apps domain. It's called the [Google Apps Extensions Console](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/) and it gives you the ability to share ownership with other developers on your domain and more. Check it out.